# Corlib not in sync when building Unity games with mdtool in OSX

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, mono

Unity3D, a popular game engine, packages a version of mono (and monodevelop) with its install. Recently I installed Xamarin Studio, keen to play with it. Later I followed some online guides for building unity's SLN files via the command line from the sln's directory:

```
/Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build -t:Build
```

I got this error:

```
Rewriting config files...
Corlib not in sync with this runtime: expected corlib version 636, found 96.
Loaded from: /Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll
Download a newer corlib or a newer runtime at http://www.go-mono.com/daily.
```

I figured that Xamarin Studio had brought a new mono runtime with it, and that was version 636. The mdtool I was running expected verison 96, because Unity ships with an older version of mono (.net 3.5 I think?).

So I uninstalled Xamarin Studio, and re-installed Unity to hopefully overwrite the mono runtime with the old version. Still get the error.

I notice above that the mscorlib.dll is not pulled from `Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current`, but 2.10.2. Why is that? How can I make this build work? Any more information I can give you?

Comment: I recently got interested in Xamarin Studio for Unity development in well. Please post an answer if you fix this problem.

Comment: @golergka do you know if mdtools worked for you before xamarin studio?

Comment: what version of Unity is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because unfortunately the question is now totally redundant (all packages involved are now completely different, three years later).